# unable to resolve class org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml @Grab('org.yaml:snakeyaml:1.17') Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I am unable to use @Grab in Jenkins pipeline. Need help here. following is the error.

```
     org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
    WorkflowScript: 1: unable to resolve class org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml
     @ line 1, column 1.
       @Grab('org.yaml:snakeyaml:1.17')
       ^

    1 error
```

Following is the pipeline code
**test.groovy**

```
@Grab('org.yaml:snakeyaml:1.17')
import org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml


node{
    stage('test'){
        Yaml parser = new Yaml()
        def a = """
---
environment: production
classes:
  nfs::server:
    exports:
      - /srv/share1
      - /srv/share3
parameters:"""
        parser.load(a)

        print(parser.load(a))
    }
}
```

The error occurs in pipeline with definition "Pipeline script from SCM" and works fine with definition "pipeline script" and Script console
Following code works with Script Console (Manage Jenkins -> Script console)

```
@Grab('org.yaml:snakeyaml:1.17')
import org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml

  Yaml parser = new Yaml()
        def a = """
---
environment: production
classes:
  nfs::server:
    exports:
      - /srv/share1
      - /srv/share3
parameters:"""
        parser.load(a)

        print(parser.load(a))
```

**output**

```
[environment:production, classes:[nfs::server:[exports:[/srv/share1, /srv/share3]]], parameters:null]
```

Comment: I think the issue is with  Groovy sandbox, because in 2nd example it runs without sandbox

Answer (score 3):

> [Groovy Grab](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/grape.html#_quick_start) uses [Ivy](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/) to manage the recovery of jars. You need to add [Shared Groovy Libraries Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Pipeline+Shared+Groovy+Libraries+Plugin). By default, it gets jars from [maven central](https://search.maven.org/), but you can specify other repositories with the annotation @GrabResolver. *Taken from [here](https://tcollignon.github.io/2017/07/10/How-To-Use-third-party-libraries-in-Jenkins-Pipeline.html)*

Also, you can add jar file to `./.groovy/grapes/org.yaml/snakeyaml/jars/snakeyaml-1.17.jar` in you Jenkins Home directory.

And the second case does not use this library and use [standard](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-utility-steps/#-readyaml-read-yaml-from-files-in-the-workspace-or-text) `readYaml` `writeYaml` functions from [Pipeline Utility Steps](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-utility-steps/#pipeline-utility-steps)